# Counting the number of times the largest number occurs

Tags: c

I cant figure out how to count the number of times the largest number was entered. please help. if i initialise s to 0 it doesnt count the first number if its the highest.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void)
{

    int times=0,n,m,i,max;

    printf("How many numbers(n) you going to enter:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    max=m;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&m);
    if(m==max)
    times++;
    if(m>max)
    max=m;

    }
    printf("The Largest Number is %d and was entered %d times",max , times);

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `times` to `1`:

```
if(m == max) {
    times++;
} else if(m > max)
    max = m;
    times = 1;
}
```

And initialize it to `1`:

```
int times = 1, n, m, i, max;
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Sorry, I missed the `max = m` part.

Comment: OH YA! thanks guys. guess my brain is kinda foggy to think of any logics.